# Execute stored procedure in Excel PowerQuery

Tags: sql, excel, powerquery

I'm trying to get a stored procedure running without using VBA.
I have the Excel file with the Start Date (`B1`) and Enddate (`B2`):

```
+---+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+---
| # | A               | B               | C               | 
+---+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+---
| 1 | Start Date:     | 01.01.2019      |                 |
+---+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+---
| 2 | End Date:       | 31.01.2019      |                 |
+---+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+---
```

Testing the statement in the Power Query Editor seems to work just fine.

```
= Sql.Database("dbserver", "datanase", [Query="exec co_liste '01.01.2019', '31.01.2019'"])
```

However, changing the dates in the query to values found in `B1` and `B2` cells is the challenge for me. Any help very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Please tag your database and possibly show the stored proc code as we need to see the parameter types.